# Method of Moment Estimator on function

Tags: integration, analysis, statistics, parameter-estimation

For an assignment i need to calculate an estimator using the method of moments, assuming a> 0.
$$f(x)=x/(2*a)*e^{(|x|/a)}$$
I calculated $E(X)$ and E($X^2)$, but if a is a positive number the Integral is $\infty$
What should I do in this situation or is this just the answer, that there is no estimator?

Comment: Is there a domain restriction or something? Otherwise you indeed have some issues with this being a valid PDF.

Comment: More likely a typo.  $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2a^2}e^{(-|x|/a)}$ is a plausible pdf across the reals, with mean $0$ and variance $6a^2$